# Query selected dimension members (tostring)

Tags: mdx

I wonder if this is possible.  I want to create a calculated member that will show which dimension member is selected by a user.  This member could then be used as a string to build responsive report titles (in PowerBI likely).

I've played with NAME, UNIQUENAME along with CURRENTMEMBER and such, but didn't get far, honestly I barely know where to start or if it's even possible.

For example.   Say I have a country  and city dimension to filter a host of measures and the user filters by "United States" and chooses a city (or three).   I'd like to be able to retrieve "United States"  as well as which cities were selected as a string and add it to a report title possibly to get a title like "Population stats for " city, city, city, " in ", country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sort of do that, take a look at how i print my slicer axis. Currentmember works when one value is used in your case you may want multiple values.

with member measures.Country
as

(existing  [Customer].[Country].members).item(1).name

member measures.City
as
 SetToStr(existing  [Customer].[City].[City].members)

```
select 
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],measures.Country,measures.City }
on columns,
[Product].[Category].[Category]
on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
where 
([Customer].[Country].&[United States],
{[Customer].[City].&[Chicago]&[IL],[Customer].[City].&[Denver]&[CO],[Customer].[City].&[Los Angeles]&[CA],[Customer].[City].&[New York]&[NY]}
)
```

Result

[image]